# To apply my video skin to every video tag (vanilla java script)

Tags: javascript

What Im trying to do is scan the document for every video tag and apply my custom skin to it.

The code below will only render the first instance, I have got it to apply the id of "video" to all video tags.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("video").length = 0) {}else{

  var vid, vidSkin, playbtn, defaultBar, progressBar, loadingBar, skipPointer, curTime, durTime, mutebtn, volumeSlider, userVolume, fullScreenBtn;

  for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("video").length; i++) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("video")[i].setAttribute("id", "video");
  }

  function intializePlayer() {

      vid = document.getElementById("video");

      //Removes and default elements
      video.controls = false;

      //Finds any video tags and creates the skin
      var vidAsChild = vid.parentNode;
      var vidWrap = document.createElement('figure');
      // set vid as child
      vidAsChild.replaceChild(vidWrap, vid);
      // set element as child of vidWrap
      vidWrap.appendChild(vid);
      vidWrap.setAttribute("id", "videoContainer");
      vidWrap.setAttribute("data-fullscreen", "false");
      // creates the controls after a video tag with an id video
      function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
          referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
      }
      var vidCtrl = document.createElement("nav");
      vidCtrl.setAttribute("id", "videoControls");
      vidCtrl.innerHTML = '<div id="defaultBar"><div id="progressBar"></div><div id="loadingBar"></div><div id="skipPointer"></div></div><button id="playPauseBtn"></button><button id="muteBtn"></button><span id="curTime">0:00</span> / <span id="durTime">0:00</span><input id="volumeSlider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1"><button id="fullScreenBtn"></button>';
      insertAfter(vid, vidCtrl);

   }

  window.onload = intializePlayer;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have got it to apply the id of "video" to all video tags.

IDs should be unique. That's why only the first one works. Either change your ids to classes, or increment your ids. Here's one possible solution

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("video").length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("video")[i].setAttribute("id", "video" + (i + 1));
}
```